# Make histogram in python with list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need some help making a histogram in python

Got some code like this:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = []

with open('paths_finished.tsv','r') as tsv:
    paths = [line.strip().split('\n') for line in tsv]
    newPath = paths[16:]
    counter = 0


for k in range(0,len(newPath)):
    path = newPath[counter][0].count(';')
    counter +=1

    print path
```

if i print path, i get a list with numbers like (9, 5, 1, 3, 12 , 7, 5, 9) and so on.
Now i have to make a histogram of path. Any can help with that?

UPDATE:

My tsv file contains this:

```
['36dabfa133b20e3c', '1249525912', '112', '14th_century;China;Gunpowder;Fire', '2']
['20418ff4797f96be', '1229188046', '139', '14th_century;Time;Isaac_Newton;Light;Color;Rainbow', '1']
['08888b1b428dd90e', '1232241510', '74', '14th_century;Time;Light;Rainbow', '3']
['08888b1b428dd90e', '1232241601', '167', '14th_century;15th_century;Plato;Nature;Ultraviolet;Color;Rainbow', 'NULL']
['4cb0068c36658716', '1248654953', '253',  '14th_century;Time;Science;Nature;Weather;Sunlight;     <;Sun;Earth%27s_atmosphere;Ultraviolet;Color;Light;Rainbow', '3']
['1082b6b8501a04b1', '1248791776', '218', '14th_century;Christianity;Bible;God;Nature;Earth%27s_atmosphere;Ultraviolet;Optical_fiber;L    ight;Rainbow', '3']
['390ae528683f78ab', '1250727252', '66', '14th_century;Time;Astronomy;Light;Rainbow',   'NULL']
['0d57c8c57d75e2f5', '1283956474', '391',
```

My path prints this:

```
12
6
4
4
6
6
4
4
8
4
4
```

and alot more numbers.

Comment: Whats inside your tsv file?

Comment: Alot, some paths for example

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: Yes. i will update my thread in a moment.. 2sec

Comment: We have only used the path you see on row[3] and counted how many path there are in each line and putted that into a list.

Comment: Okay, I'm just writing some code up now to generate the histogram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully this is what your looking for?

```
path2 = list(set(path)) ## gets the unique values in the list

histo = []

for i in path2:
    histo.append(path.count(i)) ## add the number of occurances to the histo list

plt.bar(path2, histo)
plt.show()
```

Giving this as the output:
[image]

To add axis names you can add this code:

```
plt.suptitle('Title', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('Number', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Freq', fontsize=12)
```

**EDIT** Based on the uploaded tsv file:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = []

with open('paths_finished.tsv','r') as tsv:
    paths = [line.strip().split('\n') for line in tsv]
    newPath = paths[16:]
    counter = 0

items = []
for k in range(0,len(newPath)):
    path = newPath[counter][0].count(';')
    counter +=1
    items.append(path)
    print path

print items


path2 = list(set(items)) ## gets the unique values in the list

histo = []

for i in path2:
    histo.append(items.count(i)) ## add the number of occurances to the histo list

plt.bar(path2, histo)
plt.suptitle('Title', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('Number', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Freq', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Giving the output:
[image]

Comment: No add it after the print path code you have. I'm not sure if this is what you want though? Are you wanting to plot the frequency of the numbers in path? or plot the numbers in path against the first column of the tsv file?

Comment: just want to plot the frequency of the numbers in path with a histogram.

Comment: What line is it coming from?

Comment: from this one: path2 = list(set(path)) ## gets the unique values in the list

Comment: What does your 'print path' output?

Comment: Take a look on top, i added something more what path prints.

Comment: Right, I'm gonna change the code round a bit. Do you have to use a path? or can I change it to a list?

Comment: you may change it ;) i'm not expert in python, so i don't know what is wrong / right

Comment: Okay, give me a few minutes to get it working for you

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload the whole tsv file to dropbox or some other file hosting so I can run my code on the whole file?

Comment: You can download it here : http://snap.stanford.edu/data/wikispeedia/wikispeedia_paths-and-graph.tar.gz

its the file inside the gz file

Comment: Okay, the file looks a bit different from what you added to the question?

Comment: Not that much.. if you scroll down.

Comment: There is only one instance of 434 which is making the graph so bunched towards 0

Comment: thanks man.. looks nice

then i just have to use zoom it python :) greeat